# Linux UART command line return

Tags: linux, command-line, serial-port

I am connected on the linux by serial conection (UART)
And my question:
why the command line return different control symbols?

For example:
ls command return list of files but some files are separated by two spaces -> 0x20 0x20 and other one are separated by 0x0D 0x0A or another just by 0x09
Why its like that and how can I use just one format?
Its a problem for me, because I would like to do some automatization.
[UART <-> linux communication pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0kgL.png)

Thank you very much

Comment: `0d` is carriage return, `0a` is newline. This is used to go to the next line.

Comment: The output of `ls` is printed in columns, so some filenames are separated by spaces, then it goes to the next line.

Comment: Use `ls -1` to print each file on its own line.

Comment: At first, there are at least two data mode for uart, one is raw mode, another is cmd mode, in which tty will add 0x0d 0x0a by default(based on your linux tty/uart design); second, data format return from your uart device, sometimes depending on your devices, e.g. 0x20, 0x09 MAY BE inserted in your uart device side.